# How to remove the android notifications bar?

Tags: android, android-notification-bar

I know that adding `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"` to the manifest removes the title, but what do I do to remove the notifications bar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"`.

Please use this judiciously. Users like being able to see their notifications, signal strength, battery charge, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that worked well. By the way, I plan to use fullscreen in a game.

Comment: @WRU4Android: Games are a fairly common use case for this particular theme, so users should not be surprised by it.